# Kotlin Android Emulator java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: https//10.0.2.2:3000

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, connection

I have been trying to get the Android emulator to start up a simple login/registration program with a locally costed MySQL database. However when I attempt to run the code in provides the following error, and I am uncertain as to why.

> Blockquote
> 2021-11-25 15:29:40.840 13032-13032/com.example.accentus_login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.accentus_login, PID: 13032
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accentus_login/com.example.accentus_login.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: https//10.0.2.2:3000
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: https//10.0.2.2:3000
> at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:454)
> at com.example.accentus_login.Retrofit.RetrofitClient.getInstance(RetrofitClient.kt:13)
> at com.example.accentus_login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

This is the line of code where the base URL is set up:

```
object RetrofitClient {
    private var ourInstance:Retrofit?=null
    val instance:Retrofit
        get() {
            if(ourInstance==null)
                ourInstance=Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https//10.0.2.2:3000") // 10.0.2.2:3000 is the localhost on emulator
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            return ourInstance!!
        }
}
```

This is where the API to connect to the url is initiated

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Init API
        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance // < Initialization of connection
        myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS::class.java)


        login_button.setOnClickListener{
            login(edt_email.text.toString(),edt_password.text.toString())
        }

        register_button.setOnClickListener{
            register(edt_email.text.toString(),edt_password.text.toString())
        }
    }
```

I am not entirely certain why it believes the local host is an illegal URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the colon after the protocol `https`.

Exchanging

```
https//10.0.2.2:3000
```

with

```
https://10.0.2.2:3000
```

should do the trick.